# Error:Kotlin: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, maven, reactive

Получаю ошибку с Kotlin, хотя в приложении нигде Kotlin не использую и зависимости Kotlin не было у меня но все равно получал эту же ошибку. Что б исправить добавил зависимость Kotlin c версией и той что 1.1.15 и 1.1.50 пробовал, все равно ошибка эта же.

[image: Получаю ошибку с Kotlin, хотя в приложении нигде Kotlin не использую и зависимости Kotlin не было у меня но все равно получал эту же ошибку. Что б исправить добавил зависимость Kotlin c версией и той что 1.1.15 и 1.1.50 пробовал, все равно ошибка эта же.]

Comment: Так просит-то 1.5.1, судя по тексту ошибки, а Вы пишете, что 1.1.15 и 1.1.50 добавляли.

Comment: Добавьте файл gradle или pom.xml из проекта